# How to improve "Eliminate render-blocking resources" for Lighthouse report (PWA)?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

My first attempt at a PWA is here:
https://flowster.app/calculators/freight-class-calculator/

And I'm trying to get 100% in Lighthouse for all the categories :)

[image]

I read the "Learn More" page but couldn't understand how to deliver Bootstrap CSS inline, for example.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

**What this means**

“Eliminate render-blocking resources” means that all resources (CSS/JS) which are required for the first view (top fold) should be part of the ***html itself*** (inline or script or style block); all the other CSS/JS (which is used somewhere below) can go to their other separate files;

This way, the browser will be able to paint/render the first view quickly and then go on to load the other CSS/JS files;

**How to go about it**

I [went through this myself](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/optimizing-website-zero-budget-my-journey-akber-iqbal-mcp-mcts) and realized that within the bootstrap.css i was hardly using 15% of the classes... you may also get the hint of unused css classes within lighthouse also. So this is where you can selectively include only relevant classes in your HTML;

JS will be trickier. Going on, to make this first view functional, you can insert vanilla Javascript (inside the HTML) for the navigation, carousel etc. which is better/faster than bootstrap.js;

hope it helps... Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You should only load the CSS and JS in the `head` that are actually required to load the current 'view' (I deliberately did NOT say 'page'). This does NOT mean that you should inline them. You can perfectly load them from a CSS or JS file. You should load the rest of the CSS and JS in the `footer` (CSS or JS files are fine here too).

In the case of a single page application (SPA) that is also a progressive web app (PWA), this is only your opening/splash screen... easy enough. It should be very easy to get a 100% score on that. But, when you are talking about a website in which it is unclear what the 'first page' is... it becomes an almost impossible task. A clever CSS in JS or inline solution could do the trick, but would be quite difficult to build.

There is however a much easier solution for websites. I wrote [how to get a 100% Google Lighthouse score](https://www.usecue.com/blog/how-to-get-a-100-google-lighthouse-score/), which focusses on websites only. TLDR: just omit the frameworks. It might not be a solution for every case, but for those situations where it is possible, it is definitely the way to go.